# Ajax call fail and reloads page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call that sends some JSON to be instered into the db. However when the ajax is fired it will just refresh the page and nothing is inserted. No error message is displayed.

The Ajax method

```
 function send_track(track) {
            var mainpath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
            var json = JSON.stringify(track);
            var url = mainpath + '/API/Track/Update';                

            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: url,
                data: json,
                statusCode: {
                    200 : function() {
                        $('#messagePlaceholder').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">' +
                                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                                '<strong><fmt:message key="error.success" />: </strong><fmt:message key="error.track.saved" /></div>');
                    },
                    400 : function() {
                        $('#messagePlaceholder').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">' +
                                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                                '<strong><fmt:message key="error.error" />: </strong><fmt:message key="error.track.notsaved" /></div>');
                    }
                }

            });
        }
```

The Create method

```
@PUT
@Path("/Create")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response Create(@Context HttpServletRequest request, TrackVM track) {
    try {
        HttpSession s = request.getSession();
        if (s.getAttribute("User") == null) {
            throw new Exception("Not logged in");
        }

        User u = (User) s.getAttribute("User");
        track.setUserID(u.getID());
        int trackID = _trackDao.AddTrack(track.Convert());

        if (!AddTiles(track.getTiles(), trackID)) {
            _trackDao.DeleteTrack(trackID);
            throw new Exception("Tiles not added");
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
}
```

When I put a breakpoint inside the Create method and run this in debug mode it will insert the data into db.

EDIT

The button wich starts the event

```
<button id="saveButton" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="save_track()"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span> <fmt:message key="text.save" /></button>
```

save_track() fills in the track object and sends it to send_track()

Comment: When are you calling the method send_track(track) ? If it's bind to a button or form, then use event.preventDefault(); to prevent the refresh of the page

Comment: what calls the send_track function? can we see that part of your html?

Comment: Thanks it is fixed with the event.preventDefault, I also changed the inline onclick to a jquery .click event

Answer (score 0):

**change the request method PUT by POST**

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: url,
                    data: json,
                    statusCode: {
```